# Replacement of Time class functionality and Understanding of DateTime classes in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, time

I was working on an Android application that have a massive use of [Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) class to do a Time/Dates conversions and calculations.

Now this class was deprecated and i asked to replace all the helper methods that uses it to another ones.

I have a lot of misunderstanding about how the Date/Time Class works, each class have a large difference than the other in the way that it manipulate the time.

Also the time it self has a lot of complexity:

- Unix Time stamp (Seconds from Jan. 1 1970 in 32 bit format)
- UTC: Is the time Standard and it's accurate than GMT00
- GMT: is a Greenwich time and we can calculate timezone based on it.

and etc.

I have a lot misunderstand about how can Time/Date classes manipulate time and dates based on it's wide range difference.

For Example:

This peace of code:

```
Time dayTime = new Time();
dayTime.setToNow();     
// we start at the day returned by local time. Otherwise this is a mess.
int julianStartDay = Time.getJulianDay(System.currentTimeMillis(), dayTime.gmtoff);
```

What i the replacement of it? what is the benefit of

> dayTime.gmtoff

Also, should i use:

- GregorianCalendar class

or

- SimpleDateFormat class

or

- Calendar class

or

- something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Joda-Time

Yes, date-time work in general is surprisingly confusing and tricky.

Yes, you should use something else than the classes you listed. The old date-time classes bundled with early versions of Java are a mess. They were the industry's valiant first effort at taking on this difficult subject. But ultimately they failed, proving to be flawed in both design and implementation. I am referring to java.util.Date/.Calendar, java.text.SimpleDateFormat, and their siblings. Avoid them.

Even Sun & Oracle gave up on these old classes, agreeing to supplant them with the new java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. This new framework was inspired by the success of Joda-Time.

Instead of using the old classes, add the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library to your Android project.

I recall there is some alternate packaging of Joda-Time expressly for Android to work around some limitation in Android about slow loading. I would look into that for deployment, but to get started you can use the regular Joda-Time jar.

I'll not show any example code here as you can find many hundreds of examples by searching StackOverflow.

## java.sql

For database work, use the classes in the the java.sql package: java.sql.Timestamp, .Time, and .Date classes.

Some day JDBC drivers will be updated to work directly with the new java.time types. But until that day use the new conversion methods added for those old classes in Java 8 and later.

The java.sql classes are only used for getting data in and out of databases. For all other aspects of your coding stick with the java.time classes.

## Time Zones

As for time zones, your writing is not quite clear as to the exact nature of your confusion.

All date-time handling is internally done as a count from [epoch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)). Both the old classes and java.time use an epoch of the first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). The old classes count milliseconds; java.time counts nanoseconds.

As for UTC and [GMT](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenwich_Mean_Time), for practical purposes in business apps they are the same. Read Wikipedia if you really want to know. But in regular Java work, you can think of them as synonymous.

All other time zones are defined as [offset-from-UTC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset)/GMT. We need some arbitrary point on earth to define as the dividing line, the reference point. For historical reasons, the Royal Observatory in Greenwich, London, England became that point. Clocks in [Kolkata India](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata) are set five and a half hours ahead of that time, while clocks in [Montréal Canada](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal) are set five (or four) hours behind that time.

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) in java.time is a moment on the timeline always in UTC, basically just a count-from-epoch. You can think of a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) as an Instant *plus* a time zone, a `ZoneId`. If we get the current moment by calling `Instant.now` and the adjust it by applying time zones for Kolkata, Paris, and Montréal, we would get three `ZonedDateTime` objects. All three would represent the same simultaneous moment, and each contains *the same count-from-epoch* internally. They are different only on that they display a different [wall-clock time](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

Keep in mind that a time zone is a combination of an offset-from-UTC *and* a collection of rules for handling anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). Those rules include past, present, and future adjustments that need to be made in addition to the adjustment for offset-from-UTC. Besides DST, other adjustments include, for example, various time-keeping practices that were altered in various places in Europe during the World Wars.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a robust answer but I have used the following code when parsing dates from MySql for my Android applications. I also have found the Java Date class confusing because most of it is deprecated but I have found that the [GregorianCalendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class to meet most of my needs.

One nice thing is that `new GregorianCalendar();` will instantiate to the current time. You can use another constructor to specify a specific time zone.

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
 Date date = format.parse("2012-12-13 14:54:30"); // mysql datetime format
 GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
 calendar.setTime(date);
 System.out.println(calendar.getTime());
 int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
 System.out.println(month);
```